# Rstudio requires keras 2.0.0, although I installed it through Python

Tags: python, r, keras, deep-learning, rstudio

I have installed and updated `keras v.2.2.0` on Python. However, when I try to build a DNN model using Rstudio's `keras` package it gives me following warning.

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
Keras loaded from keras Python module v1.2.2, however version 2.0.0 is required. 
Please update the keras Python package.
```

As I specified, I have installed `keras v.2.2.0` on Python, but still gets this warning.

Any idea how to solve this? Is there something I should do on Rstudio?

Comment: It's telling you that it requires the version `2.0.0` (`however version 2.0.0 is required.`)

Comment: I already updated to version 2.2.0. Should I specifically instal version 2.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your version of Keras 2.2.0 is installed in the environment you are running in. You need to check whether it is installed in the same environment in anaconda navigator.